# include_once is including the html as text

Tags: php

I am trying to use the `include_once` like

```
<?php include_once "emailform.html"; ?>
```

but instead of including it html code, PHP is including it as simple text and the output looks like

```
��<div class="well widget"> <div class="widget-header"> <h3 class="title">'O1/H�� ,3 �' F'E</h3>
```

any help?

Comment: post your emailform.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .html file may not be encoded in **UTF-8**. Open it in an editor and make sure it's saved as ***UTF-8***.

Answer (score 2):

`include_once()` is not for what you are doing. Use `readfile()` to output the contents of the html:

```
readfile('yourhtml.html');
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you must get rid of [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better way to include HTML content is http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php