# Display html page in php file

Tags: php, html

I know a bit of HTML but I'm trying to learn PHP right now. Say I have a simple .php file like this:

```
<?php

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I'm on a mac, how do I get my browser to display the webpage represented by the HTML in this file? When I try open the PHP file it shows the actual HTML code, not the header. Apologies for the noobie question, I'm going through a PHP tutorial right now and the instructor did not elaborate on how to actually display the HTML inside the .php file so I'm a bit confused. He's running it through his localhost it seems.

Comment: maybe you can take a look here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447437/include-once-is-including-the-html-as-text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447437/include-once-is-including-the-html-as-text)

Comment: Your sample.php file is okay. It will show you html generated code by browser and you can code within php.

Comment: Please read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php) to learn how to install PHP with a webserver. PHP need to be processed server-side : your browser cannot do it, as for html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the deal with php, is that your browser can't run php code, that is done by the server. You'll need to get a local server to run it then. Since you're on a mac this should be alright:

https://www.mamp.info/en/

Once you've got that running, you'll need to put your php file into the 'htdocs' folder of the MAMP stack install. After that you can access it by navigating to localhost/filename.php

Answer (score 0):

You need a local host to run your php script like MAMP for your mac. simply you can use free web hosting service from different online  free host web server like [Hostinger](http://www.hostinger.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a php file directly on your web browser that your are using.You need to have a local server host in-order to run your php file. Try downloading an using wamp server,Apache etc.

http://www.wampserver.com/